# IGBT won'tn turn on despite 12V Gate to Emitter pulse

Tags: mosfet, igbt

[image]

IGBT is RGTH40TK65GC11
R1 and R2 are not populated
TCC4426 is a Mosfet driver ic.
Good 12 volt, 1 uS pulse on the Gate referenced to ground
I've tried several IGBTs with 12 volt or lesser drive - no difference

I have a 200 volt dc supply to which the negative is tied to ground(emitter) and the positive to a 100K resistor which then connects to the collector.
Always read 200 volts across collector to emitter.
What am I missing?

Comment: Please don't be offended if I ask the obvious: the schematic shows that the emitter is tied to the same ground as the drive circuitry - is this also true in your as-built system?

Comment: No decoupling capacitors?

Comment: What do you expect to happen?  Are you looking at the collector voltage with an oscilloscope?  You **are** aware that an IGBT is _not_ an SCR: it only stays on for as long as the gate is held high.  Moreover, an IGBT is _not_ a FET: it's way slower.  I would expect that if I handed an IGBT -- even a fairly small one like this -- a \$1 \mu \mathrm s\$ pulse on the gate, I'd get a current response that would be slow, and it may not turn "on" all the way.

Comment: I am aware that an IGBT is not an SCR. I expect to see ~200 volt pulse.  I chose an IGBT with switching speeds in the tens of Nano seconds.  I understand the resultant 200 volt pulse may not be perfect but I see absolutely nothing with my scope

Comment: Show scope screenshots of the gate and collector waveforms.

Comment: I changed my pulse to 1 millisecond to see if speed was an issue.  No change.  With the scope I see a clean 12 volt, 1 ms pulse on the gate (referenced to the emitter)  On the collector I see a steady 200vdc